# Issue with Multiselect field and related entries

Tags: relations, field

I am having an issue outputting news stories that are filtered via a multi-select field, newsCategory is the the multi-select fied handle.

Here is my code

```
<div class="search-results search-results--col-three">
{% set selectedCategory = entry.newsCategory %}
{% set latestNews = craft.entries.section('news_entries')
.relatedTo({
 targetElement: selectedCategory,
 field: 'newsCategory'
  })
 .orderBy('postDate desc')
 .all() %}

{% for news_entry in latestNews %}
    {# Display the filtered news entries as needed. #}
{% endfor %}
```

There are no errors with the code but it doesn't output any stories, if I take out

```
 targetElement: selectedCategory,
 field: 'newsCategory'})
```

I get all my stories output without the filter, so it looks like the issue is with this part of the code. I am using craft 4.5 and I'm not sure if the change to entification has affected this syntax .Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't [executed](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/element-queries.html#executing-element-queries) your [element query](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/element-queries.html).

Try swapping out:

```twig
{% set selectedCategory = entry.newsCategory %}
```

for:

```twig
{% set selectedCategory = entry.newsCategory.ids() %}
```

Comment: Ok tried that and I get this error : Neither the property "ids" nor one of the methods "ids()", "getids()"/"isids()"/"hasids()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "craft\fields\data\MultiOptionsFieldData".

Comment: Sorry, I read your question too fast without paying enough attention! If you're using a multiselect (a questionable decision IMO, as they are a UI fraught with UX problems), then you can't use `relatedTo`, because the values are not _elements_. Only elements are "related to" each other. Instead you'd need to use a simple custom field query: https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/element-queries.html#querying-with-custom-fields ... However, I'd recommend that you switch to using a proper category selector instead of a plain text multi-select field - it's a lot cleaner and more powerful.

Comment: Yes I think you are right; the custom field query is messy too. I'm going to switch to a category selector